# Format file size in Unix in readable format

Tags: file, unix, usability

When I do `ls -l` I get

```
-rw-r--r--   1 jboss    admin  **26644936** Sep  1 21:23 MyBig.war
```

How do I print it as below

```
-rw-r--r--   1 jboss    admin  **26,644,936** Sep  1 21:23 MyBig.war
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper way to format `ls` output is to specify [`BLOCK_SIZE`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#Block-size).

Saying:

```
BLOCK_SIZE="'1" ls -l
```

would achieve your desired result.

Quoting from the above link:

> Some GNU programs (at least `df`, `du`, and `ls`) display sizes in “blocks”.
>   You can adjust the block size and method of display to make sizes
>   easier to read.

---

> A block size specification preceded by `‘'’` causes output sizes to be
>   displayed with thousands separators.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`:

```
$ ls_output='-rw-r--r--   1 jboss    admin  26644936 Sep  1 21:23 MyBig.war'
$ echo $ls_output | sed -e :a -e 's/\(.*[0-9]\)\([0-9]\{3\}\)/\1,\2/;ta'
-rw-r--r--   1 jboss    admin  26,644,936 Sep  1 21:23 MyBig.war
```

Above sed command repeatedly replace the last 4 digits `####` with `#,###`.

- `-e :a`: Make a label named `a` for `t` command.
- `ta`: Jump to `a` if substitution was successful.